# Как использовать QXlsx подключая ее не в корень проекта а в отдельную директорию?

Tags: c++, cmake

В документации написано как нужно подключать:

```
add_subdirectory(QXlsx)
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE QXlsx::QXlsx)
```

Перед этим нужно копировать каталог в корень проекта. Так все работает отлично.
Но мне нужно отделять сторонние библиотеки от основного проекта.
К примеру я хочу чтобы было так `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/QXlsx`
Но так не работает. Cpack не может найти файлы

```
CPack readme resource file:
third-party/QXlsx/../README.md" could
  not be found.
```

Подскажите как лучше сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Исправил пути в cmake файле и в CpackConfig. Добавил файл README.md в каталог QXlsx. Но мне кажется это не совсем верно, мне кажется это костыль, но это работает. Может кому поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы отделить сторонние библиотеки от основного проекта и разместить их в другой директории, вы можете воспользоваться подходом, который позволит явно указать местоположение библиотеки QXlsx. Вот как это можно сделать:

Сначала загрузите и соберите библиотеку QXlsx в отдельной директории (например, ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/QXlsx) так, как вы делали ранее.

Убедитесь, что в директории ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/QXlsx есть файлы библиотеки, включая файлы заголовков и библиотеки (если они нужны).

В вашем основном проекте, когда вы настраиваете его с помощью CMake, укажите путь к библиотеке QXlsx, используя переменную CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. Например:

**cmake**

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/QXlsx")
find_package(QXlsx REQUIRED)
```

> Затем укажите библиотеку QXlsx как зависимость для вашей цели:
> **cmake**

```
target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE QXlsx::QXlsx)
```

Убедитесь, что ваш проект собирается и работает должным образом с этой

> конфигурацией.
>
> При сборке вашего проекта с помощью CPack, укажите
> CPACK_PACKAGE_RESOURCE_FILE_README для указания пути к файлу README.md
> вашей библиотеки QXlsx. Например:

**cmake**

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_RESOURCE_FILE_README "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/third-party/QXlsx/README.md")
```

Теперь при упаковке вашего проекта CPack должен правильно найти и включить файл README.md из указанной директории.

Этот подход позволяет вам держать сторонние библиотеки отдельно и более четко указывать их местоположение для вашего проекта CMake.

Comment: По-моему, вы неправильно используете форматирование цитат. Исправьте, если будет время.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но README.md изначально не находится в каталоге QXlsx. Вы можете попробовать создать пустой проект, добавить из репозитория библиотеку и поместить ее в другой каталог.